# How do I use clojure.set/difference? Why won't it work on a PersistentSet?

Tags: clojure, set

The following code:

```
(require '[clojure.set])
(println (clojure.set/difference '("a" "b" "c" "d") '("c" "d" "e" "f")))
```

gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList (repl-1:47)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  Shouldn't this print out ("a" "b")?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are lists, not sets.

`(println (clojure.set/difference #{"a" "b" "c" "d"} #{"c" "d" "e" "f"}))`

Comment: Is there a list version of difference? Or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: JBristow: No, but you can turn your list into a set: (clojure.set/difference (set '(1 2)) (set '(1 3))) => #{2}

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't need to `require '[clojure.set]`. It seems to be automatically loaded with core. Just starting a repl, and typing the below works (at least for me).

```
user=> (clojure.set/difference (set '(1 2 3)) (set '(3 4 5)))

\#{1 2}
```